# Intersecting 2 big datasets

Tags: c#, python, database, bigdata

I have a giant (100Gb) csv file with several columns and a smaller (4Gb) csv also with several columns. The first column in both datasets have the same category. I want to create a third csv with the records of the big file which happen to have a matching first column in the small  csv. In database terms it would be a simple join on the first column.

I am trying to find the best approach to go about this in terms of efficiency. As the smaller dataset fits in memory, I was thinking of loading it in a sort of set structure and then read the big file line to line and querying the in memory set, and write to file on positive.

Just to frame the question in SO terms, is there an optimal way to achieve this?

EDIT: This is a one time operation.

Note: the language is not relevant, open to suggestions on column, row oriented databases, python, etc...

Comment: please comment on the downvote so I can improve the question.

Comment: How often will you perform the join? If more than once, read both files into a database.

Comment: I don't have experience, but you may want to look into HDF5 for data that big.

Comment: 100GB is not so big. Terabyte DB's are commonplace

Comment: @MitchWheat, only once. Do you think it is worth to import both tables into the DB in this case?

Comment: Does the CSV change? meaning, do you continue to receive updates to the file?  If it is a 1 time task, pushing this into a db and querying it is trivial.

Comment: For a 1 time operation, I think your approach is fine...  It'd probably be a 15-20 line python program.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
import csv

def main():
    with open('smallfile.csv', 'rb') as inf:
        in_csv = csv.reader(inf)
        categories = set(row[0] for row in in_csv)

    with open('bigfile.csv', 'rb') as inf, open('newfile.csv', 'wb') as outf:
        in_csv  = csv.reader(inf)
        out_csv = csv.writer(outf)
        out_csv.writerows(row for row in in_csv if row[0] in categories)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I presume you meant 100 gigabytes, not 100 gigabits; most modern hard drives top out around 100 MB/s, so expect it to take around 16 minutes just to read the data off the disk.

Comment: thanks! Can this be somehow optimized to read/compare/write by chunks?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only doing this once, your approach should be sufficient. The only improvement I would make is to read the big file in chunks instead of line by line. That way you don't have to hit the file system as much. You'd want to make the chunks as big as possible while still fitting in memory.

If you will need to do this more than once, consider pushing the data into some database. You could insert all the data from the big file and then "update" that data using the second, smaller file to get a complete database with one large table with all the data. If you use a NoSQL database like Cassandra this should be fairly efficient since Cassandra is pretty good and handling writes efficiently.